# Ajax to the same page sending empty value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a form on my page:

```
<form id="extended-search" >
<div class="input-container">
<select class="select" name="sex" id="sex">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">M</option>
<option value="2">F</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type = "button" class="searchButton" value = "Show" onClick="submitSearch();">
<img id="loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="working.." />
</form>
```

And jQuery code on the same page:

```
function submitSearch() {
        var submitSearchData = jQuery('#extended-search').serialize();
        var selectedValue='<?php echo $_POST['sex'];?>' ;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: submitSearchData,
            url: "feed.php",
            success: function () {
            alert(submitSearchData);
            alert(selectedValue);
            }
        });
    }
```

Everything works(first alert returns, for example, sex=1, but the second is empty) fine, but `$_POST['sex']` is empty. I've been trying:

To use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.searchButton').click(function(){            
        submitSearch();
    });
});
```

To remove: `url: "feed.php",` from AJAX.

To make: `data: {sex: submitSearchData},`

To add and change `dataType` in AJAX.

But everything is still the same. `$_POST['sex']` is still empty. How do I pass `$_POST var($_POST['sex'])` through AJAX on the same page?

Comment: Why are you using inline PHP with AJAX anyway?

Comment: you talk about var selectedValue='<?php echo $_POST['sex'];?>';? Added this one just for test, to have fast look on this var.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

use this code for getting the selected option

```
var selectedValue=$('#sex').val();
```

Because you are not submitting the form and because of this you are not getting `$_POST['sex']` value. You have to use `jquery` or `jaavscript` for getting the currently selected option.

Comment: I have simillar code on the other page which works fine. When i use .serialize() i got all the selected values in form, but the problem i cannot pass it on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var selectedValue='<?php echo $_POST['sex'];?>';
```

doesn't do what you seem to expect it to do. The `submitSearch()` function only gets called when the button is clicked (twice, but more on that later). When you `POST` to your PHP, the JavaScript doesn't get executed (since there's no click event) and when your JavaScript gets called, the `$_POST['sex']` isn't set to anything.

You can get what the PHP returns in your JavaScript like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: submitSearchData,
    url: "feed.php",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("response from PHP: " + data);
    }
});
```

So if your feed.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sex'])):
    switch ($_POST['sex']) {
        case 0:
            echo "You didn't select anything";
            break;
        case 1:
            echo "You selected male";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "You selected female";
            break;
    }
else:
?>
// all your HTML
<?php endif; ?>
```

then the `alert` will come back with `response from PHP: You selected male` (or `You didn't select anything` or `You selected female`) depending on what the selection was.

Since you already bind click to your button with jQuery in the `<head>` your HTML should only be:

```
<input type = "button" class="searchButton" value = "Show" />
```

otherwise it will call `submitSearch()` twice.

Comment: I forgot to say, yes i've got if(isset($_POST['sex'])) checker, and it says the var is empty. Yes i am calling my script once, i'd say i trying different ways, but still same result.

Comment: @DmitryAntonenko Are you trying to make sure that your PHP is correctly seeing the `<option>` in your `<select>` submitted by your AJAX POST or are you trying to get the result of your PHP to show up on the page?

Comment: I am trying to get $_POST['sex'] var filled with the 0,1 or 2 trough AJAX script, which sends it from form to the same page. The same code works fine for me, when i am using it in different place, but i send $_POST vars on the different page, not to the same.

Comment: @DmitryAntonenko Your AJAX code to POST is working fine. You can confirm that with the code in my updated answer.